# Desktop shuts down (actually not..?) randomly

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

I got brand-new PC 2-3 months ago, assembled myself.

I think I already have enough knowledge about softwares / hardwares, but I think it is out of my hands.

After assembled my PC, it eventually / randomly (sometimes after 3~7 days, or only after 1 day) shuts down without any notifications (Bluescreens, Event Loggers, etc)- but actually it didn't shutdowned - screen turns out black and sound goes off (Windows goes down) but PC fans and LEDs still working, mainboard's status LED changes to orange, and if I try to turn off PC at this situation (with pressing power button long time), it's not working- so I must unplug or turn off the switch of power cable.

**What I've done / Maybe not a problem**

- RAM (already changed RAM to another)
- PSU (bought new one, with more capacity)
- Heating / Cooling (when PC shutdowns, HWInfo said that My GPU/CPU's maximum temp is 70-75℃ while gaming.
- Software Issues (Already tried clean install of Windows)
- BIOS Reset / Update

**Specs**

- Mainboard : ASUS TUF GAMING B550M
- CPU : AMD 5600x
- GPU : RTX3070
- RAM : 8gb x2
- PSU : FSP 800W (bought with very-enough PSU, because at first I thought it is PSU problem)
- Storage : M.2 nvme SSD 1TB / SATA SSD 1TB

Any suggestions? I'm suffering pain about 3 months.

Comment: Are you sure your GPU isn't faulty?

Comment: @Burgi I'm not sure, but I stress-tested my gpu and it passed easily.